# Binary Search Tree Remove Function

Tags: c#, binary, binary-tree

I am creating a remove funciton for a binary search tree and ran into a question.

```
private BinaryTreeNode<T> BinaryDelete(BinaryTreeNode<T> root, T value)
    {
        if (root == null)
        {
            return root;
        }

        int compareResult = value.CompareTo(root.Value);

        if (compareResult < 0)
        {
            root.Left = this.BinaryDelete(root.Left, value);
        }
        else if (compareResult > 0)
        {
            root.Right = this.BinaryDelete(root.Right, value);
        }
        else
        {
            if (root.Left == null)
            {
                return root.Right;
            }
            else if (root.Right == null)
            {
                return root.Left;
            }

            root.Value = this.FindMinLeftLeaf(root.Left);

            root.Left = this.BinaryDelete(root.Left, root.Value);
        }

        return root;
    }

    private T FindMinLeftLeaf(BinaryTreeNode<T> root)
    {
        while (root.Left != null)
        {
            root = root.Left;
        }

        return root.Value;
    }
```

So, basically, root.Value = this.FindMinLeftLeaf(root.Left); is searching in the left child of the root. While I was studying, I've saw some examples, where the search is done in the right child, so its kinda confusing.
In short:
Are those two lines supposed to be like that

```
root.Value = this.FindMinLeftLeaf(root.Right);
root.Right= this.BinaryDelete(root.Right, root.Value)
```

or the way I have them in the first example?

Comment: Everything on the left should be smaller and the right should be larger so you want to either take the max from the left or the min from the right to replace the removed value at the root.

Comment: So, the correct way would be to take the Right node and in the FindMinLeftLeaf method find the min from the left node of this original right node?